# Collateralized Loan Obligation - reliable source of information

Tags: leverage, debt

Can someone provide me with some reliable source of information about CLOs? Especially some scientific articles etc. Google or wiki are good for starters and I would like to get some examples, comparisons, parties of contract, usage and more.
Any help would be nice.